# Command-line access to OS X's keychain - How to get e-mail address associated with account

Tags: macos, bash, keychain

I'm writing a Bash command-line tool that accesses the keychain for emulating a web browser to communicate with web pages.

It's quite straightforward to get the password stored in the keychain from there:

```
PASSWORD=`security find-internet-password -gs accounts.google.com -w`
```

But it's a bit more tricky to extract the email address, as the most specific command you get for this returns a lot of information:

```
$security find-internet-password -gs accounts.google.com
/Users/me/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="accounts.google.com"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="my-email-address@gmail.com"
    "atyp"<blob>="form"
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x32303135303333303134333533315A00  "20150330143531Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>="rimZ"
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>=<NULL>
    "icmt"<blob>=<NULL>
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x32303135303333303134333533315A00  "20150330143531Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>="/ServiceLogin"
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000 
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>="htps"
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>=<NULL>
    "srvr"<blob>="accounts.google.com"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
password: "my-password"
```

How would you extract the account e-mail address from the line starting with `"acct"<blob>=` and store it, say, to a variable called `EMAIL`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using multiple `grep`, `cut`, `sed`, and `awk` statements, you can usually replace them with a single `awk`.

```
PASSWORD=$(security find-internet-password -gs accounts.google.com -w)
EMAIL=$(awk -F\" '/acct"<blob>/ {print $4}'<<<$PASSWORD)
```

This may be easier on a single line, but I couldn't get the `security` command to print out an output like yours in order to test it. Plus, it's a bit long to show on StackOverflow:

```
EMAIL=$(security find-internet-password -gs accounts.google.com -w | awk -F\" '/acct"<blob>/ {print $4}')
```

The `/acct"<blob>/` is a regular expression. This particular `awk` command line will filter out lines that match this regular expression. The `-F\"` divides the output by the *field* given. In your line, the fields become:

- The spaces in the front of the line.
- `acct`
- `<blob>`
- `my-email-address@gmail.com`
- A null field

The `{print $4}` says to print out the fourth field.

By the way, it's usually better to use `$(....)` instead of back ticks in your Shell scripts. The `$( ... )` are easier to see, and you can enclose subcommands to execute before your main command:

```
foo=$(ls $(find . -name "*.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EMAIL=`security find-internet-password -s accounts.google.com | grep acct | cut -d "=" -f 2`
EMAIL="${EMAIL:1:${#EMAIL}-2}" # remove the brackets
```

Explanation:

- `grep acct` keeps only the line containing the string "acct"
- `cut -d "=" -f 2` parses that line based on the separator "=" and keeps the 2nd part, i.e. the part after the "=" sign, which is the e-mail address enclosed within brackets
- `EMAIL="${EMAIL:1:${#EMAIL}-2}"` removes the first and last characters of that string, leaving us with the clean e-mail address we were looking for

Comment: Some explanation of your solution would probably go a long way to improving your answer.

Comment: If you're doing `grep` and `cut`. Use `awk` instead. I'll have an `awk` answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DavidW. - I added an explanation.